# mongodb console update change data type

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

The original data is:

```
{"u":1}
```

The type of 'u' is Int. 
After I run command in mongod console:

```
update({},{$set:{"u":0}})
find({})
```

data indeed become

```
{"u":0}
```

looks pretty ok. But when I use C++ driver to read them:

```
bson.getIntField("u")
```

Crash. The reason is type 'u' is Double! That means mongod's update command change u's type soundlessly.

Why? and how to prevent this?

P.S
mongodb version is 2.6.6 linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any numeric value is inserted or "changed" as a `Double` by default. For other "types" use the [`NumberInt()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/#numberint) or [`NumberLong()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/#numberlong) for the respective type you expect to read in your C++ or other type sensitive code:

```js
update({},{ "$set":{ "u": NumberInt(0) }})
```

or:

```js
update({},{ "$set":{ "u": NumberLong("0") }})
```